# Trying to get property of non-object SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

I am currently using the following code to retrieve information from a REST api.

```
$url = "http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products%28upc=".$upc."%29?apiKey=(API KEY)";

$xmlfiledata = file_get_contents("$url");

$xmldata = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfiledata);

$saleprice = $xmldata->products->product->salePrice;
echo $saleprice;
```

However, PHP is returning this error.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in FILE LOCATION on line 132
```

line 132 is:

```
$saleprice = $xmldata->products->product->salePrice;
```

I have verified that the URL being produced is correct. The xml document in question is here (I simplified it for the sake of simplicity).

```
<products currentPage="1" totalPages="1" from="1" to="1" total="1" queryTime="0.006" totalTime="0.014" canonicalUrl="/v1/products(upc="635753489873")?apiKey=xr2r8us3dcef7qdjnecbvh6g" partial="false">
<product>
<salePrice>529.99</salePrice>
</product>
</products>
```

How to fix?

Comment: That's an `Notice`, not an `Error`, wich you can suppress with `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) on PHP.net, I believe you'd need to do the access like this:

```
$saleprice = $xmldata->product[0]->salePrice;
```

`$xmldata` is actually your "products" level, so I don't think you need `...->products->...`

Comment: Why the down vote? Please provide more information on how to make this answer more acceptable.

Comment: You can also use xpath, to avoid errors when your xml is not always with the same structure.